# Using variables in Javascript.replace

Tags: javascript, android, regex, variables, webview

I am trying to inject the replace method for javascript in webview for android.

This code works:

```
       {
            mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){" +
                    "document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('hello', 'hi');" +
                    "})()");
            }
```

Instead of putting the string  in the method, however, I want to use variables. I tried using regex but it does not seem to work.

```
        {
            String old = "hello";
            String new = "hi";

            mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){" +
                    "var ol = new RegExp(old,'g');" +
                    "document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(ol, new);" +
                    "})()");
            }
```

Is there something off with my code?

Comment: So you want to evaluate that?

Comment: `new RegExp(" + old + ",'g')` and `.replace(ol, " + new + ");`

Comment: var doesnt seem to recognize the text inside as a string...any way to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to quote out the variables when passing them into a string like that

```
{
    String old  = "hello";
    String _new = "hi";

    mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){" +
                    "var ol = new RegExp("+old+",'g');" +
                    "document.body.innerHTML = " +            
                    "document.body.innerHTML.replace(ol, " +_new+ ");" +
                    "})()"
    );
}
```

Note that `new` is a reserved keyword, and shouldn't be used as a variable name

Comment: sorry, i thought this would work and marked it as answer but it ended up not working when i put it in my code.